# How to move a file to the desktop using the terminal?

Tags: image-processing

I want to add an image to the desktop to get information about it with exif, but I don't know how to add the image in desktop or how to copy it in a terminal.

I'm learning how to use the terminal and I've created an image folder using the terminal. Now I'm wondering how to add an image that I already have saved on my computer by using the terminal.

I'm wondering if I can add an image to the folder without having to go through finder.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

You can use the `mv` command to move files using the following syntax:

```
mv /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

Replace `/path/to/...` with absolute or relative paths.

You can also use a tilde `~` at the beginning of the path as a shortcut to your user's home folder.  So the destination directory for your Desktop is `~/Desktop`:

```
mv /path/to/source ~/Desktop
```

So let's assume you have a file `image.jpg` in your current working directory and you want to move it to your user's desktop, you would use the following command:

```
mv image.jpg ~/Desktop
```

---

Unless you're writing a script, it's usually a better practice to copy with `cp` rather than move with `mv`.  The reason is that when you move a file, the original file at the source path will be deleted. If you copy, you can make sure that everything is okay before you choose to delete the file at the source path.

Comment: but when i do that nothing happen, i must to cp image from for example the desktop the laptop to the desktop linux how i do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you trying to transfer files between two different computers? If so, that's a very different question than the one you've asked. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?